# Seamless Page Loading Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, loading

I came across this [site](http://www.buildinamsterdam.com/cases) and noticed that when you navigate from page to page by clicking a project or scrolling down and clicking an arrow, the transition seems to be perfectly seamless. What method are they using to achieve this? Are they making sections hidden and revealing them through transition? Is it a trick whereby they show what the page that's loading is going to look like and I don't notice the snap? Is there something much fancier going on in the background?

The only other stack post about this kind of this I could find refers to:

```
history.pushState()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Katie

Comment: They are using GSAP https://greensock.com/gsap, a powerful JS framework for animations of all sorts.

Comment: @SergioAlen Thank you I'll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress installation with the Bia theme and this plugin

https://lt.wordpress.org/plugins/versatile-jquery-slider/installation/

Check out this page as another example :-)

http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/

Comment: Cool thank you! Is there any way to replicate this without relying on WP and the plugin?

Comment: @kathrynm Check out that second link called SudoSlider. That is a jQuery plugin that can be used to serve the same purpose without needing to install wordpress. :-)

Comment: @kathrynm Please remember to mark as answered if this has answered your question to your satisfaction! :-)